# iterating through an xml file maintaining hierarchy levels

Tags: c#, xml, charts

i am trying to write a function to iterate my xml file - then use the data found to produce my tree diagram again in dotnetcharting.

For example, if i have the following (terrible, but just made up!)xml file

```
<root>
    <Player>
        <firstname/>
        <lastname/>
     </Player>

     <Team>
         <Name/>
          <Country>
              <League>
              </League>
         </Country
     </Team>
</Root>
```

then the idea is that i would have a tree diagram where i would have my root node, then stemming from this i would have player and team. Then each of the subnodes for each, until eventually the last nodes would be the data.

```
  XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
    }
  }
```

I know i can read the xml file like this, but i have no way of maintaining any form of heirarchy so i cant tell dotnetcharting whats a parent node of what?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use recursion for this. Personally I would have a function that returns a `TreeNode` and if the current node contain child element nodes then calls itself such as:

```
static class XmlProcessor
{

    public static TreeNode ProcessXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Move to first element
        while(reader.Read() && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element){}
        return ParseNode(reader);

    }

    private static TreeNode ParseNode(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) return new TreeNode(reader.Value);
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement) return new TreeNode(reader.Name);

        TreeNode current = new TreeNode(reader.LocalName);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                current.Nodes.Add(ParseNode(reader));
            }
            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                return current;
            }
        }
        return current;
    }

}
```

This could be called from the application using:

```
TreeNode processedNodes = null;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml))){
  processedNodes = XmlProcessor.ProcessXml(reader);
}
```

The `using` block ensures that the XmlReader is closed and disposed correctly once it falls out of scope.